# How modify each Child object with adding data from Parent object when having the foreign key (from Parent) inside child Object?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

How, in Dashboard Component, modify each Task Item from tasksCollection so that new Key(goalCategory) and Value being the category name from queried Goal Object (queried Goal based on foreign key) is added to each Task ?
This is my attempt: https://pastecode.io/s/0srjkhqe

PS: I cut out any unnecessary code, such as getGoalById or tasksCollection definition so that only the most important code for the question remains.

```
// Dashboard Component
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

goalCategory!:any; // parameter to which new value is supposed to be assigned with the help of getGoalCategory method on each iteration inside tasksArray

ngOnInit() {
    this.tasksService.tasksCollection()
    .pipe(
        concatMap(tasksArray => {

          tasksArray = tasksArray.map((item:any) => {
            this.getGoalCategory(item); // method which 
            return {
              goal_id: item.goal_id,
              description: item.description,
              id: item.id,
              isMainGoal: item.isMainGoal,
              name: item.name,
              goalCategory: this.goalCategory // -> new key with value from Goal!
            }
          })
          return tasksArray;
        })
    )
    .subscribe(
        (tasks:any) => {
          console.log(tasks);
        }
      )
}

}
```

Comment: could you try using `.pipe(map(tasksArray => tasksArray.map(item => ...))` instead of `concatMap`?

Comment: @MaartenDev Ok, I tried your suggestion https://pastecode.io/s/x3t4n7r0 , however I get 'goalCategory' as undefined check out this screen -> https://pasteboard.co/9gUhEFS8mLvn.jpg

Comment: I suspect there is something of with the timing on the part of the code execution, meaning I'm trying to asses the value which has not yet been retrived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `async` and `await` to wait on `getGoalCategory` to complete. Using `Promise.all` you can wait until all goals are loaded

Example setup:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.tasksService.tasksCollection()
            .pipe(
                map(tasksArray => {
                    return tasksArray.map(async (item:any) => {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            goalCategory: await this.getGoalCategory(item)
                        }
                    })
                })
            )
            .subscribe(async tasks => {
                   const completedTasks = await Promise.all(tasks);
                   console.log(completedTasks);
                }
            )
    }

    getGoalCategory(item:any) {
        return new Promise((res) => {
            this.goalsService.getGoalById(item.goal_id)
                .subscribe(d => {
                    res(d[0].category);
                })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why are you using 'Goal' type inside tasksArray - ?
+ inside the subscribe I want to console log all modified Tasks not all Goals ;)

Comment: My bad, that should be something like the `Task` class, I always try to use a specific type instead of `any` in Typescript

Comment: Could you look into getGoalCategory method on line 95 inside this code -> https://pastecode.io/s/0srjkhqe ....it seems that I can only access this.goalCategory parameter inside subscribe in that method, not outside of that method

Comment: I tried your solution with await,  const goalCategory still returns 'undefined'

Comment: Ok, now it works , thank you very much. I wanted to upvote but 'need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote,'

Comment: I think you can still mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons if this helped you